# Receiving double quotes after serialization

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I'm using `Macross.Json.Extensions` and there is a method which accepts `Interval interval`. When I serialize it, I expect to get it as `15`, not `\"15\"`. In this case, the serialization puts double quotes and basically the output of `asd` is `\"15\"`, instead of juts `15`. How do I fix it?

```cs
public void Test(Interval interval)
{
    var asd = JsonSerializer.Serialize(interval, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
    }); // Equals to: \"15\". Expected: 15
    var intervalMinutes = int.Parse(interval.ToString());
}
```

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum Interval
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    OneMinute,

    [EnumMember(Value = "5")]
    FiveMinute,

    [EnumMember(Value = "15")]
    FifteenMinute,

    [EnumMember(Value = "30")]
    ThirtyMinute,

    [EnumMember(Value = "60")]
    OneHour,

    [EnumMember(Value = "240")]
    FourHour,

    [EnumMember(Value = "1440")]
    OneDay,

    [EnumMember(Value = "10080")]
    OneWeek,

    [EnumMember(Value = "21600")]
    FifteenDays
}
```

Comment: `EnumMemberAttribute` allows you to **rename** the attribute during serialization.  Using it, you renamed `FifteenMinute` from "FifteenMinute" to `"15"`.  If you want to modify the value of `FifteenMinute`, you could 1) Don't use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` and just set the value in the enum itself: `FifteenMinute = 15` 2) Write a custom converter that serializes the enum as an integer and remaps the value.

Comment: @dbc, thank you! Well explained!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EnumMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-6.0) exits to serialise enumerable values as their symbolic – identifier – names, rather than the actual numeric value used at runtime.

In this case the value passed to the attribute is a minute count, rather than using that as the value of the enum's values (which is odd: serialising a value that could change by the introduction of another value, eg. `TwentyMinutes`).

This would be far better not using `EnumMemberAttribute` and setting each member directly:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum Interval
{
    OneMinute = 1,
    FiveMinute = 5,
    FifteenMinute = 15,
    ThirtyMinute = 30,
    OneHour = 60,
    FourHour = 240,
    OneDay = 1440,
    OneWeek = 10080,
    FifteenDays = 21600
}
```

Comment: In that case `interval = FourHour`. Is there a way to get it numeric?

Comment: Oh nvm, I removed the `JsonConverter` attribute and then `JsonSerializer.Serialize(interval)` actually returns `15` as a number. Thanks